# Stanford-NLP doesn't allow me to use expressions with spaces in my regex

Tags: regex, stanford-nlp

I'm using Stanford NLP (presently TokensRegex) and I'm encountering a problem : the (ab|cd) regex works, but not the (a b|cd) one, probably because it is not recognized as a full expression... The problem is I have to do regex that match both an expression and its acronym (for example, United Kingdom and UK along). 
Can you help me, please ?

Greetings from France !

Comment: Could you provide the sample rule file you are using, the command or Java API call you are using, and an example input sentence and what result you want?

Comment: I assume this is not solved. I'm having the same issue with the following rule `Inserci(ó|o)n (de\s)?cord(ó|o)n umbilical` it recognizes "Inserción cordon umbilical" but not "inserción de cordon umbilical". It's the "de" what's not being recognized.  Im using tokenizer and regexner, among other anotators and with the java api (the annotate method from StanfordCoreNLP class).